# Car animation rotating wheels

Tags: android, imageview, rotateanimation

I am working in an app that shows different cars and the user needs to choose one. When you press on next the car moves out of the screen and the new one comes in.

My resources are:

- Car's body
- Car's wheel

(I need them to be separated because when the car moves I need to rotate the wheels)

I wanted to avoid `AbsoluteLayout` so my `CarView` extends `RelativeLayout. Here's the code:

```
public class CarView extends RelativeLayout {

    private ImageView mBody;
    private ImageView mLeftWheel;
    private ImageView mRightWheel;
    private float mScale;

    public CarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void initView(Car car) {
        mScale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Context ctx = getContext();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        mBody = new ImageView(ctx);
        mBody.setLayoutParams(params);
        mBody.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_body);
        addView(mBody);

        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        mLeftWheel = new ImageView(ctx);
        mLeftWheel.setLayoutParams(params);
        mLeftWheel.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_wheel);
        mLeftWheel.setPadding(0, dpToPx(79), dpToPx(188), 0);
        addView(mLeftWheel);


        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        mRightWheel = new ImageView(ctx);
        mRightWheel.setLayoutParams(params);
        mRightWheel.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_wheel);
        mRightWheel.setPadding(dpToPx(203), dpToPx(75), 0, 0);
        addView(mRightWheel);
    }

    public void startMoving() {

        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        rotateAnimation.setDuration(900L);
        rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

        mLeftWheel.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
        mRightWheel.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    }

    private int dpToPx(float dp) {
        return (int) (dp * mScale + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Basically what I am doing is placing the body of the car and then using padding to place the wheels where they should be.

After reading [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg20288.html) android developer's thread I notice that `RotateAnimation` rotates the whole view including the padding making the wheels to do some strange movement.

How should I fix this?
Can you think of a better way to place the wheels `ImageView` instead of using padding?

Another issue I have is that in a certain point I want the wheels to stop moving, but the method [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#cancel%28%29) in `Animation` is Since: API Level 8 and I need this to work on 1.5. How should I stop the rotation?

Comment: I have tested this and I can confirm that margins do not rotate, as the API says: "This space is outside this view's bounds." ([ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you think of a better way to place the wheels ImageView instead of using padding?

The "right answer", I think, is to create your own layout manager. Leastways, that's what we've been told. I tried it once and couldn't get it to work.

The not-quite-so-right answer may be margins rather than padding -- I haven't tried animating a `View` with margins and so I do not know if margins rotate. Padding should rotate, since that is considered "inside" the widget.

The even-less-right answer is to use a transparent `View` as a shim, rather than margins *or* padding. Align your `ImageView` relative to the shim with no margins or padding, with the shim's size set to position your `ImageView` where you want it.

The well-if-you-know-how answer is to dump the widgets entirely and just draw it all using the `Canvas` and 2D graphics APIs. Angry Birds, for example, presumably does not use `ImageViews`.

Comment: I fixed it placing each wheel in a `RelativeLayout` with the padding applied to the it instead of the wheels. Thanks!